# How to add hyperlink to objects in PowerBI other than http links in table

Tags: powerbi

I found a helpful video on youtube to put an http Link in a table and use it to access website from powerBI report. I am not able to put the link on anything other than a table though. Can anyone help regarding the same please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible yet.

I'd suggest voting for [this idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/34281916-hyperlink-in-visuals) on the Power BI Ideas forum.